# What are the risks to disabling driver signature enforcement in Win 8?

Tags: drivers, windows-8, digital-signature

In order to use the communication software for Arduino in Windows 8 I'm forced to permanently disable driver signature enforcement.

I did this for sometime with windows 7 without contracting a virus or inducing catastrophic system instability. However, Microsoft tech support has informed me that this is "definitely a bad idea" in Windows 8 but did not specify why.

Any one have any idea what they meant by "bad idea"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you disable signature enforcement, nothing will prevent you from installing broken, poorly-written, or malicious drivers, which can easily crash your system, or worse.

If you're careful about the drivers you install, you should be fine.